# XMPP Web chat. Chache architecture

Tags: xmpp, strophe, muc

I am developing XMPP based web chat using stroph js via web sockets. I have 5-10 chats at the same time. user could swipe chates in runtime. So live history should be showed to user. There is some best practies about message storing. So 5-10 chats. each chat live about 10-30 minutes. so this time i should correctly show messages in chats. where I should store messages. just arrays, or some db. Also i fond that strophe spit all messages from chat after join to it. should i be joined to each chat at the same time, and rejoin each time on open chat?